# Custom urls same controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Suppose I had a controller that look like this:

**AController.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AController extends Controller {

    public function doThis(){...}
    public function doThat(){...}
    public function doThing(){...}
}
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/doThis', [
    'as' => 'acontroller.dothis', 'uses' => 'AController@doThis'
]);

Route::get('/doThis', [
    'as' => 'acontroller.dothat', 'uses' => 'AController@doThat'
]);

Route::get('/doThis', [
    'as' => 'acontroller.dothing', 'uses' => 'AController@doThing'
]);
```

Is there a better way than using `Route::get()`? I want my route to be automatically `ControllerName.methodName` and the url to be `/methodName` without having to explicitly use `Route::get()`

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for an "implicit controller" (docs [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#implicit-controllers)).

If you define your route like:

```
Route::controller('/', 'AController');
```

All of the routes underneath the specified prefix (first parameter) will get routed to that controller.  Laravel then expects the method names to be defined as a combination of the HTTP verb and the route.

So, your controller would be:

```
class AController extends Controller {
    public function getDoThis(){...} // GET to /doThis
    public function postDoThat(){...} // POST to /doThat
    public function anyDoThing(){...} // any verb to /doThing
}
```

Comment: I was looking at that too, but how do I specify the route? such as ['as' => 'ControllerName.methodName']

Comment: @Margo You don't have to. The routes are implied by the methods defined on the controller. By defining the `getDoThis` method, that implicitly defines the `/doThis` route.

Comment: Actually I just learned it is bad to use implicit controller because you'll get something like this `doThis/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}` for the route. I'm still thinking if there's another way of doing this, to avoid using controller

Comment: @MargoEastham While there are pros and cons to using implicit controllers, I wouldn't classify the issue you mentioned a a con. That is just Laravel's way of allowing route parameters to your implicit routes. If you need them, they're there; if you don't, they can be safely ignored.